# Angular date conversion UTC to EST

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been trying to convert this time into EST `"date": "2020-04-27T14:44:42Z"`. I am using angular and  can get it into this format `myFormat: 'MMM-DD-YYYY h:mm A'` but can't seem to adjust the time to reflect est. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Angular's `date` pipe to format the date? It should reflect the time zone of the current user.

Comment: Also with Angular's date pipe you can set the time zone, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using momentjs

moment timezone makes is easy and convenient to convert+format. Command for npm install moment-timezone (this solution supports DST neutral TZ string 'America/New_York' instead of EST/EDT)

```
npm install --save moment moment-timezone
```

Code

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

// ...
// ...

const dateFormattedInEST = moment("2020-04-27T14:44:42Z").tz('America/New_York').format('MMM-DD-YYYY h:mm A');
```

> Output: Apr-27-2020 10:44 AM

Moment gives lot of formatting options. Documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

### Using Angular pipes

Can be done using angular pipes as well (as pointed out by JSON Derulo).

> Note: the format string are different from momentjs

```
{{"2020-04-27T14:44:42Z" | date : 'MMM-dd-YYYY h:mm a' : 'EDT'}}
```

> Output: Apr-27-2020 10:44 AM

If you want to get hold off string for any other manipulation

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

// ...
// ...

const dataAsStr = datePipe.transform("2020-04-27T14:44:42Z", 'MMM-dd-YYYY h:mm a', 'EDT');
```

> Output: Apr-27-2020 10:44 AM

Comment: This solution will work, however this seems totally overkill to me. Formatting a date for a specific time zone is possible with Angular's Date Pipe, and even with the Intl.DateTimeFormat browser API.

Comment: moment provides much more features than angular pipe. I expanded my answer using Angular pipes as JSON Derulo indicated

Comment: But it's such a big overhead, and it bloats up the application. If you don't need it, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Both answers are provided above. It is upto developer what he wants to choose. If moment is already used in application they can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solution that I am applying now. You can use the method `toLocaleString` to do this.

Example 1:

```js
const convertUTCDateToLocalDate = date => {
    const newDate = new Date(date.getTime()+date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

    const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    const hours = date.getHours();

    newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

    return newDate;
}

const _date = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(new Date("2020-04-27T14:44:42Z"));
_date.toLocaleString(); // "4/28/2020, 6:44:42 AM"
```

Example 2:

```js
const _date = new Date("2020-04-27T14:44:42Z");
const _est_date = _date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}); // "4/27/2020, 10:44:42 AM"
```

Just change the locale based on the requirement from your project.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString